# How to use @injectMocks thats requires constructor

Tags: java, mockito

I'm using mokito to inject a mock. This object extends a class that requires a contructor with arguments. How to mock this object that requires constructor arguments and pass this arguments as mock too?

Example class

```java
public abstract class AbstractClassRequireContructor{
    protected AbstractClassRequireContructor(Object param) {
}

public class ClassA extends AbstractClassRequireContructor{

    public ClassA(Object param) {
        super(param); // required by super class
    }
}
```

Test class

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ClassATest{

    @Mock 
    private Object paramMockToBeAddedByConstructor; 

    @InjectMocks
    private ClassA classA; // requires contructor from super class

    @BeforeEach
    void setup{
        when(paramMockToConstructor.anyMethod()).thenReturn(anyValue);

        // how to inject mocked argument?
        classA = new ClassA(paramMockToBeAddedByConstructor); // this doesn't work
    }

    @Test
    void test(){
        when(classA.anyMethod()).thenReturn(anyValue); // use injectMock class normally
    }

}
```

Is there any another strategy to work arroung this better?

Answer (score 0):

Drop the instantiation of a new `ClassA` object. It should work without it as follows:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ClassATest{

    @Mock 
    private Object paramMockToBeAddedByConstructor; 

    @InjectMocks
    private ClassA classA;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup{
        when(paramMockToConstructor.anyMethod()).thenReturn(anyValue);
    }

    @Test
    void test(){
        when(classA.anyMethod()).thenReturn(anyValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: if I do this way... the treating on setup desen't work and I receive an argument in constructor classA with no effect from setup

Comment: What do you mean? I am not following you.